# Generators of the intersection of twelve ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I have to show that the intersection of the twelve ideals $$(X\pm 1, Y\pm 1), (X\pm 1, Z\pm 1), (Y\pm 1, Z\pm 1) \subset \mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$$ is the ideal $$\Big( (X^2 −1)(Y^2 −1),(X^2 −1)(Z^2 −1),(Y^2 −1)(Z^2 −1)\Big).$$ Is there an easy way to do it, maybe some combinatorial way or something?

Thank you.

Comment: The $12$ ideals are all the minimal prime ideals over the second ideal, called $I$. If $I$ is radical, then $I$ equals the intersection of all those $12$ prime ideals. In order to show that $I$ is radical localize at the maximal ideals. These have the form $M=P+(f)$, where $P$ is one of the $12$ ideals and $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in the missing variable from the two generators of $P$. For instance, $M=(X-1,Y+1,f(Z))$ with $f(Z)$ irreducible. Then the localization $I_M$ equals the localization of $((X-1)(Y+1),(X-1)(Z^2-1),(Y+1)(Z^2-1)$ at $M$.

Comment: But we can't have $Z^2-1\mid f(Z)$, so one of the factors $Z\pm1$ doesn't show up in $f(Z)$. This tells us that the localization of the ideal $((X-1)(Y+1),(X-1)(Z^2-1),(Y+1)(Z^2-1))$ at $M$ equals the localization of $((X-1)(Y+1),(X-1)(Z\pm1),(Y+1)(Z\pm1)$ at $M$, and this is a radical ideal since it is an intersection of three prime ideals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ be an element of the intersection of the twelve ideals. At first we have $m \in (x\pm1,y\pm1)$, so minimally we must have:

$y-1|m \lor x-1|m ,y+1|m \lor x-1|m  ,y-1|m \lor x+1|m  ,y+1|m \lor x+1|m$

There is a symmetry among these conditions, so assume WLOG that $y-1|m$, which satisfies the first and third minimal conditions. In order to satisfy the second and fourth, we must either have $y+1|m$ or $x^2-1|m$ by inspection. Overall if $m \in (x\pm1,y\pm1)$, then $x^2-1|m$ or $y^2-1|m$. By applying the same logic to $(x\pm1,z\pm1)$ and $(y\pm1,z\pm1)$ we must have the following:

$x^2-1|m \lor y^2-1|m, z^2-1|m \lor y^2-1|m, x^2-1|m \lor z^2-1|m$

Again we can assume WLOG that $x^2-1|m$, in which case we must also have $z^2-1|m \lor y^2-1|m$ in order to satisfy the second condition. Therefore we have shown that $(y^2-1)(x^2-1)|m $ or $(z^2-1)(x^2-1)|m $ or $(y^2-1)(z^2-1)|m $ by symmetry and so $m \in ((X^2−1)(Y^2−1),(X^2−1)(Z^2−1),(Y^2−1)(Z^2−1)).$

It remains to show that if $n \in ((X^2−1)(Y^2−1),(X^2−1)(Z^2−1),(Y^2−1)(Z^2−1))$, then $n$ lies in the intersection of the twelve ideals, which is straightforward. After this we have basically established a one to one relationship between the intersection and $((X^2−1)(Y^2−1),(X^2−1)(Z^2−1),(Y^2−1)(Z^2−1))$

Comment: Nice try, but let's suppose that $m=(X^2-1)(Y^2-1+Z^2-1)$. I'm afraid that you can't conclude that $(y^2-1)(x^2-1)|m $ or $(z^2-1)(x^2-1)|m $ or $(y^2-1)(z^2-1)|m $.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find anything on ideals generated by more than 1 element and so I assumed the generators are multiplied together.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, I'll try to work it out this way.

Comment: @nbayo Unfortunately you accepted a wrong answer.